# Getting NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: android, exception, android-volley

I have create a service to send location on server. I am using volley library to send on server.I am getting this exception some time when app is in background.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -512
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:323)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.get(DiskBasedCache.java:119)
   at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:100)
```

Comment: Have you get any solution for it?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution on this. I used volley in foreground to send location because it is getting issue while app is in background.

Comment: It happens cause of continuing background request process of API calls. I had same issue in pagination so I solved it by putting interval